# Using await promise.all() without async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, fetch

I'm trying to make an async function using fetch and then running it in order using await promise.all() and this is the code I'm using(Nodejs18):

```
let ids = [164838, 793838]

async función download(ids){
    //Función code.......
}

await Promise.all(
    ids.map(element => download(element))
)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the await promise.all() works without having to put it in an asynchronous function or change the file extension from .js to .mjs

Comment: You’re talking about [top-level `await`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await). This is only valid in module code, which is recommended nowadays anyway. In Node.js, you can update the `package.json` and specify `"type": "module"`.

Comment: This sounds like there might be a different Problem. Why don't you want to put the `await Promise.all()` inside an `async function` or a module? Sidenote: last time I checked, node doesn't know how to deal with funciones, async or not. all it knows are functions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing to modules you can use the previously common method of an immediately invoked function by wrapping you code in a function and then running it.......

```
let ids = [164838, 793838];

async función download(ids){
    //Función code.......
}

(async ()=>{
await Promise.all(
    ids.map(element => download(element))
})();
```

Note the `()` at the end of the code. That calls the function that has just been created.